# Resetting/clearing a Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am fetching a backbone collection for a search form. I think I want to reset the collection after every search because currently the search results are just appending the new results the previous results.

Currently the @collection.reset() does absolutely nothing.

```
class ****.Views.DesignerSearchView extends Marionette.CompositeView

  className: 'tab_pane'

  id: 'search_items'

  template: JST['designer/DesignerSearchTemplate']


  itemView: (obj) ->
    new Mywebroom.Views.DesignerSearchItemsLayout(obj)

  itemViewContainer: "div"

  events: {
    'keyup #designer_search': 'search'
    'click .fa-times ': 'clearSearch'
  }

  initialize:->

    @collection = new Mywebroom.Collections.SearchItems()


  search: ->

    searchTerm = $('#designer_search').val()

    @collection.reset()
    @collection.fetch({
      data: $.param({ search : searchTerm })

      async: false
      success: (collection, response, options) ->
        console.log("designs fetch success", response)

      error: (collection, response, options) ->
        console.error("designs fetch fail", response.responseText)
    })
```

**EDIT**

Per CharlieBrowns suggestion:

```
search: ->

    searchTerm = $('#designer_search').val()

    @collection.fetch({
      data: $.param({ search : searchTerm })

      async: false
      reset: true
      success: (collection, response, options) ->
        console.log("designs fetch success", response)

      error: (collection, response, options) ->
        console.error("designs fetch fail", response.responseText)
    })
```

and

```
search: ->

    searchTerm = $('#designer_search').val()

    @collection.reset([])
    @collection.fetch({
      data: $.param({ search : searchTerm })

      async: false
      success: (collection, response, options) ->
        console.log("designs fetch success", response)

      error: (collection, response, options) ->
        console.error("designs fetch fail", response.responseText)
    })
```

But still no luck

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use collection.reset([]) to reset the collection and add 0 new models.
2. Use collection.fetch({ reset: true }) to reset the collection on every fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the help but neither seem to do the trick. Did I do it wrong possibly?

Comment: Just to be sure because the question is not 100% clear, the problem is that the search results are kept in the collection or in your composite view? Perhaps you're CompositeView is not removing the child items when you `reset()` the collection. You should `console.log(collection.toJSON())` on your `success` handler to check if the collection has the previous models on it.